# command line option parser with space in directory name

Tags: shell

I have a Python program to run in command line. It has a `'-d'` option to take a directory name after it, like this:

```
foo.py -d dir_name
```

But when I run this on a directory containing empty space in the dir_name, like:

```
foo.py -d C:/My Folder/hello
```

it splits into two parts before and after the space.

My code uses the `getopt` function to parse the command line options:

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "d:")
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print('foo.py -d <dir_name>')
    sys.exit(1)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-d',):
        dir_name = arg
        do_all(dir_name)
```

The variable `dir_name=C:/My` instead of `C:/My Folder/hello` after this. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
foo.py -d "C:/My Folder/hello"
```

That's not about Python, that's how shells work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really should remember putting the argument in the quotes :)

Answer (score 3):

Pass the arguments within quotes, like this:

```
foo.py -d "C:/My Folder/hello"
```

Alternatively, you can escape the spaces if the shell allows it:

```
foo.py -d C:/My\ Folder/hello
```

Notice that this is not a Python-specific problem: *every* command line program out there has to do this to pass strings that include spaces!